# Way to search PHP code and create necessary MySQL tables and columns

Tags: php, mysql

I know this might come off as a bit idiotic to most of you but it is really important to me. I receive numerous PHP files from someone who no longer has time for this project. He did all the PHP coding for the site and I was wondering if there was any way to create the correct tables for the website to become functional. He has stuff like:

```
$dirQuery = "SELECT s.sID, s.name, s.rank, s.branch, n.posName 
             FROM soldier s, billet b, noc n 
             WHERE s.sID = n.sID AND n.posName = b.director AND b.id = $billet";
```

And others like that, and you can see there are multiple tables and columns. Is there anyway to go through the entire coding and find out which tables I need to create, which columns, etc?

Comment: grep, sed, awk - the shell is your friend. Also a good IDE/editor has at least regex bases search (and replace) across multiple files. Place the codebase under version control so you can easily change and revert back in case things turn out to go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't tell what types the columns are just from looking at that. If you don't know what types the columns are, you can't really create the columns, and without columns, tables are kind of useless.

Comment: It seems hard to believe that he didn't create the tables on a test server while he was writing the code. I know that I can't do much coding without occasionally checking that my queries will work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of tables is relatively low, and the code fails with sensible errors when the table is missing, you can just run the code, read the error and create the tables one by one! If the number of tables is low, you will spend a lot less time doing that, than coming up with an automated solution (which would require an SQL detector + parser + extra logic to actually create the tables and columns).